# Why is the second column of the square not printed in its excepted place?

Tags: c++

sorry if the question isn't clear enough so here I am explaining more:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num;
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> num;

    for (int y = 1; y <= num; ++y){
        for (int x = 1; x <= num; ++x){
            if (x == 1 || x == num || y == 1 || y == num){
                cout << "* ";
            }

        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

This piece of code is supposed to print a square shape (framed), it's doing well except for the second column is being dragged to the left with the first column.
Here how it looks like (**actual output**):

```
* * * * * * * *
* *
* *
* *
* *
* *
* *
* * * * * * * *
```

and my **expected output** is supposed to look like this:

```
* * * * * * * *
*             *
*             *
*             *
*             *
*             *
*             *
* * * * * * * *
```

Any help? especially that I don't see any problem with my code!

Comment: You are not printing anything except "* ", so where do you expect the spaces to come from that should indent the right side of the rectangle?

Comment: @WernerHenze I wrote (else { cout << " "; }) too, still the same.

Comment: *Any help? especially that I don't see any problem with my code!* -- FYI, hardly anyone, even professional programmers, write programs, where on the first version, there are no bugs.  You see that the output isn't what you wanted, so the thing to do is to debug your code, and not simply conclude your code is "good" and just not try for yourself to debug the issue.

Comment: Pop quiz: what do you expect the shown code to print when, for example, `y` is 2 and `x` is 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not printing any spaces when you're not printing asterisks. Just add printing for that case as well:

```
if (x == 1 || x == num || y == 1 || y == num) {
    cout << "* ";
}
else {
    cout << "  ";  // to align the * to the right
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4Kae5s)